# python postgis query in QGIS problem with encode

Tags: postgis, pyqgis, python-2.7

I have the latest QGIS 2.18.6 and i try to use some postgis query using python in QGS python console.

field characters from mytable is my non-English language and in postgis have encode 'utf-8' and any time where I want to work In QGIS never haven't problem with characters encode.

but any time to use python and postgis I have any time problem with encode characters.

here the code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from qgis.PyQt.QtXml import QDomDocument
from qgis.utils import iface
import psycopg2



constring = u"dbname='database' host='postgre' port='port' user='username' password='code'"
conn=psycopg2.connect(constring)
checkCur = conn.cursor()
sqlCheck = "select * from public.mytable;"
checkCur.execute(sqlCheck)
sqlCheckRess = checkCur.fetchall()

mylist=[]

for i in sqlCheckRess :
    mylist.append(i)
checkCur.close()
conn.close()
print mylist
```

that work nice but that I take in print mylist is un-humanity language

print like this :

```
 u'2247_\u03a5\u06c6\u03b9\u04c3\u03c4\u03ac\u05bc\u03b5\u03bd\u03bf \u03c5\u03c0\u03cc\u03b2\u03b1
```

Comment: Your string is in unicode, and it print very well :`s =  u'2247_\u03a5\u06c6\u03b9\u04c3\u03c4\u03ac\u05bc\u03b5\u03bd\u03bf \u03c5\u03c0\u03cc\u03b2\u03b1'` and `print s` return me `2247_ΥۆιӃτάּενο υπόβα` It's just how the string it's store.

Comment: It's how list stores your string and if you print each one of the element it will print as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mylist=[]

for i in sqlCheckRess :
    mylist.append([x.encode("utf-8") for x in i])
```

you are appending unicode objects to the list, that's why you see those un-human characters, have a look at [this](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html). Also, I assumed that "i" is a list when you append it.

Comment: @xDias not work I get error `no attribute to encode`.any other idea ?

Comment: are you getting something like `'list' object has no attribute 'encode'`? if so somehow your `i` object is a list rather than a unicode object. You can try encoding every item on the `i` list, like this `[[x.encode("utf-8") for x in y] for y in i]`. Be aware that by doing it this way you'll end up appending a list object to `mylist`

Comment: I try some error `no attribute to encode`